# The usage of "WHO" as a conjunction

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, whiz-deletion

I've just started reading the Booker Prize-winning novel "The Sellout".

I don't know the narrator has omitted **" who"** here or he is talking about himself when he says "**indifferent to** ...":

... I never snuck into the movies or failed to give back the extra change to a drugstore cashier **indifferent** to the ways of mercantilism and minimum-wage expectations...

I mean, who is indifferent here, the Cashier or the Narrator?

Is "who" a deleted conjunction?

Comment: There's no conjunction omission. "Indifferent to the ways of mercantilism and minimum-wage expectations... " is an adjective phrase functioning as a post-head modifier. Since you are reading the book, who do you think it refers to?

Comment: @BillJ : Thanks for your comment. It's an independent sentence. It can be both.

Comment: @BillJ I even checked the French and the Italian Translations. one of them says it's the narrator and the other says the cashier.

Comment: It's not an independent sentence, not a sentence at all, but an adjective phrase headed by the adjective "indifferent".

Comment: In traditional grammar terms, *indifferent to the ways of mercantilism...* is a reduced relative clause. *a drugstore cashier [who was] indifferent to the ways of mercantilism...* That should make it obvious who was indifferent.

Comment: Even if it were some kind of 'reduced' relative clause (which it isn't), it would be a dependent clause, not an independent one which the OP seems to think it is (see their penultimate comment). In any case, it could refer to the subject "I".

Comment: It relates to *cashier.* It’s the cashier who’s unconcerned with the “ways” of the merchant(s) who own the store; it’s the cashier who’s earning a minimum wage and is unaware of the expectations of those who have hired him or her.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, that's the only sensible explanation really ... but the grammar allows for the zany interpretation also. Grammar ain't the be-all and end-all ....

Comment: This is not a great sentence. Logically, it applies to the narrator because how in the heck would he know that kind of fact about some random cashier? Hm? Also, I think he is saying he never did those things because he was not indifferent to the ways of mercantilism and minimum-wage expectations. One wonders if the editor was asleep at the wheel. Otherwise, the narrator is just full of himself. Oh wait: I just read the blurb., so maybe the narrator is stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BillJ said, *indifferent to the ways of mercantilism and minimum-wage expectations* is an adjective phrase functioning as a post-head modifier. The way it is written, it is somewhat ambiguous whether it modifies the subject (*I,* the speaker/writer) or the *cashier* (in which case the adjective phrase is an internal modifier of the noun phrase that is the complement of the preposition *to*). Grammatically, it could be either, though I should add that the absence of a comma before *indifferent* makes me think it is more likely that the writer meant it to refer to *cashier*. Unfortunately, in this case, even the context doesn't completely remove the ambiguity.

Just to make sure that the adjective phrase could indeed modify either word, note that both of these are acceptable:

*Thus British tyranny mercilessly increases the sufferings of the world, **indifferent** to the laws of humanity.* ([source;](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_United_States_Naval_I/Y1kwAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22indifferent+to+the%22&dq=%22indifferent+to+the%22&printsec=frontcover) here it modifies the subject, *British tyranny*)

*Dunn likens those who produce and market alcoholic beverages to the robbers who stripped and beat the traveller on the road from Jerusalem to Jericho (Luke 10:30-37), the drunkard to the victim of their crime, and those who passed the beaten man to a public **indifferent** to the availability of alcoholic beverages.* ([source;](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Annotated_Catalogue_of_the_Edward_C_A/zFKvimYMHloC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+a+public+indifferent+to+the%22&pg=PA275&printsec=frontcover) here the adjective phrase is an internal modifier of an NP that is the complement of a preposition)

Comment: *the sufferings of the world, indifferent*; *to a public indifferent to the availability*. Note the comma.